# Android studio lost space to coding

Tags: android-studio, spaces

I am so sorry because I dont know how to explain that bug. But it's seem i the space in left screen can not use to coding.

I used studio in few years but today I just got this problem.

Let see my attach's video. Thanks you.

[That is my video link](https://vimeo.com/269308983)

Comment: Are you sure you didn't activate Distraction free mode(check the View menu at the bottom)? https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/intellij-idea-tips-tricks-presentations/

Comment: thanks you, let take answer and i will mark this.

Comment: I've answered the question. I feel silly getting a bounty for this so if you have another question that you would like to be featured with a bounty, leave me a comment on the answer with the link and I'll set a bounty on that question for 50 points.

Comment: no need sir, easy for you but big problem for me when I can not explain or finding key to search google. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That space is specific to a Intellij/Android Studio presentation mode called `Distraction Free Mode`. You can activate/deactivate this mode by going in the `View` menu and selecting the option at the bottom.